# How to change fill using handle_click?

Tags: r, ggvis

I have a bar chart like this

```
iris %>% ggvis(~Species, ~Petal.Width)
```

and I would like to use `handle_click()` to change the `fill` of a bar to red when one is clicked. For example, if I clicked on versicolor, it should look like this

```
iris %>% ggvis(~Species, ~Petal.Width) %>% layer_bars(fill=~Species) %>% scale_nominal("fill", range = c("#333333","red", "#333333"))
```

I know I need to handle the click event, but I wasn't able to understand how by looking at the documentation. I have started with this, but I have no clue how to set up the `barRed()`:

```
barRed <- function(data, location, session, ...) {
}

iris %>% ggvis(~Species, ~Petal.Width) %>%
  handle_click(on_click=barRed)
```